# What is the r.expr() order of execution?

Tags: rethinkdb

given:

```
r.expr([
    r.table('someTable1').get(id1).update({key : 'value1'}),

    r.table('someTable2').get(id2).update({key : 'value2'})
])
.run(rethinkConnection, function(err, results) {});
```

will the items in the array which is the argument to `r.expr()` evaluate in a predictable order or in an arbitrary order?

Comment: Im aware that `r.do()` cannot gaurantee order execution, im curious if using `r.expr()` mitigates this concern

Comment: I don’t believe so, if you want predictable order use the reduce method otherwise I believe it uses a map which will execute in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r.expr([query1, query2])` sends off the queries in order, however there is no gauranteethey will be processed by the cluster in order. This may lead to race conditions. A method which will execute in order but make all query results visible to the final processing callback is:

```
var result1 = null;
var result2 = null;

r.table('table1')
.filter(function(row) {
    // return a boolean
})
.run(rethinkConnection)
.then(function(localResult) {
    result1 = localResult;
    return r.table('table2')('someField').run(rethinkConnect);
})
.then(function(localResult) {
    result2 = localResult;
    // rest of processing here
})
.catch(function(error) {});
```